# How do we define pdf of Z=XY when joint pdf of X and Y is known?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

How do we define pdf of Z=XY when the joint pdf of X and Y is known? I want to know the definition, not any theorem concerned with finding pdf of Z

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: nope! not at all

Comment: Do you know anything about the support of $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: nope we are talking about general case

Answer (score 2):

It is rather similar to a convolution.

$$f_Z(z) = \int\limits_{\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}}~ \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, z/x)}{\lvert x\rvert}~\operatorname d x$$

Where the Jaccobian of the transform $(x,y)=T(z,x)=(x,z/x)$ is used: $$\lvert\Bbb J_{T}(z,x)\rvert = \begin{Vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial z/x}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z/x}{\partial x} \end{Vmatrix} = \dfrac {1}{\lvert x\rvert}$$